# Como manter os 100 últimos objetos inseridos em um ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Como manter os 100 últimos objetos inseridos em um ArrayList? Este será constantemente alimentado mas quero manter apenas os últimos 100.

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Um Arraylist sempre adiciona novos elementos ao fim da fila. Você terá que criar um método que trate a adição, verificando antes se a lista já possui 100 itens e em caso positivo, remover o primeiro antes de adicionar um novo, usando algo como  `if(lista.size == 99){lista.remove(0);}lista.add(element);`

Comment: Eu acho de extrema importância você resolver esse problema sozinho. Então depois, jogue aí o código que você conseguiu, que agente ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais simples de resolver este problema é aplicanto o conceito de `FIFO (First in, first out)`.

Fifo refere-se a uma estruturas de dados do tipo fila.
As listas são amplamente utilizadas em programação para implementar filas de espera. Em uma fila de tipo FIFO os elementos vão sendo colocados na fila e retirados (ou processados) por ordem de chegada. A ideia fundamental da fila é que só podemos inserir um novo elemento no final da fila e só podemos retirar o elemento do início.

[image: Exemplo de execução de um código FIFO]

Você pode ver mais [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)

Além deste conceito será preciso limitar o volume de registros que vc quer armazenar, desta forma indico utilizar o [Apache Commons Collections](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1)

Se estiver utilizando maven poderá fazer o import:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Se estiver utilizando gradle

```
`compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'`
```

Basicamente você so precisa adicionar a biblioteca `commons-collections4` em suas dependencias, para exemplificar utilizei a verão 4.1.

Após fazer o import você pode criar suas listas previamente limitadas por exemplo:

```
 new CircularFifoQueue<String>(100)
 new CircularFifoQueue<Integer(100)
```

entre outros.

Para exemplificar melhor fiz um exemplo criando string aleatórias e armazenando na fila, ao final exibo os valores restantes:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Collection<String> fifo = new CircularFifoQueue<String>(100);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println(i + " - " + id);
        fifo.add(id);
    }

    System.out.println("----> Result Fifo <----");
    int i = 1;
    for (String id : fifo) {
        System.out.println(i++ + " - " + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente e mais elegante! .. vou usa-la!

Answer (score -1):

Consegui chegar no que eu queria com while..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0;i < 150 ; i++){
        arr.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }

    while(arr.size() >= 100){
        arr.remove(0);
    }

    for(String x : arr){
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

Comment: Só uma correção: este site [NÃO é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/28595).

Comment: Limite-se a colocar na resposta somente aquilo que responda a pergunta. Use os comentários (quando tiver reputação para isso) para fazer comentários adicionais, que não competem à resposta.